# Remove last character while writing to a text file

Tags: arrays, scala, file-io

I am writing the contents of the array to a text file in a comma-separated form. Here is my Scala code:

```
import java.io.FileWriter
import scala.util.Random

val N = 1000000
val writer = new FileWriter("file.txt")
val res = Random.shuffle(1 to N)
for (i <- 0 until res.length) {
  writer.write(res(i) + ",")
}
writer.close()
```

This code works fine but also adds a comma at the end like:

```
12,11,9,....,23,56,
```

I want output so that comma is not there at last place

```
12,11,9,....,23,56
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the first element solo and every element thereafter preceded by a comma.

```
writer.write(res.head.toString)
res.tail.foreach(n => writer.write("," + n))
```

Comment: ̈́,213,720,677,395,99,124,119,437,.......

This is output. First character is illegal.

Comment: `tail` on an **Array** is very expensive, I would either use `mkString` or be totally imperative and just do a while straying in `1` after printing the head.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez; True, `.tail` on an `Array` is linear. But `.shuffle(1 to n)` returns an `immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]` which my REPL realizes as a `Vector[Int]` and, according to [the docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html), a `.tail` on that is (effectively) constant. I agree, `mkString()` is a simple, straight forward solution, but this looked to be more memory-efficient.

Comment: @jwvh sure, I just thought that was an example code since OP literally wrote: _"I am writing the contents of the array to a text file"_.

Answer (score 2):

Convert a Scala collection `xs` to a comma separated string with `xs.mkString(",")`. In the case above consider

```
writer.write(Random.shuffle(1 to N).mkString(","))
```

This will ensure the last comma character is between the last two values, and the string generated is finalised with the last value instead of an extra comma character.